# Find the volume between $y = 4 − \frac{3x}{2}$ and $y=0$ and $x\in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume $V$ of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves 
about the specified line.

> $$y = 4 − \dfrac{3}{2x},\ y = 0,\ x = 0,\ x = 1$$

about the $x$-axis.

I keep getting $\dfrac{61\pi}{4}$ and its wrong. HELP! Any tips would be wonderful!!

Comment: If you have somehow calculated $61\pi/4$, can you show us your steps?

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood your given curve,

$$\begin{align}
V
=&\int_0^1 \pi\left(4-\frac{3x}{2}\right)^2dx\\
=&\pi\int_0^1 \left(16-12x+\frac{9x^2}{4}\right)dx\\
=&\pi\left[16x-6x^2+\frac{3x^3}{4}\right]_0^1\\
=&\pi\left(16-6+\frac{3}{4}\right)\\
=&\frac{43\pi}{4}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's a cone above a cylinder.

Comment: That was not in the original post title. The original post title was the curve y =4- 3x/2, in OP's exact wording.

Comment: OP changed the initial problem statement. Sorry.

Comment: Well, @kimtahe6 changed that.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
V
&=
\int_{3/8}^{1}\pi\left(4 - {3 \over 2x}\right)^{2}\,{\rm d}x
=
\pi\int_{3/8}^{1}\left(16 - {12 \over x} + {9 \over 4x^{2}}\right)\,{\rm d}x
=
\pi\left.\vphantom{\Huge A}%
\left\{16x - 12\ln\left(x\right) - {9 \over 4x}\right\}\right\vert_{3/8}^{1}
\\&=
\pi\left[%
16 - {9 \over 4} - 6 + 12\ln\left(3 \over 8\right) + 6
\right]
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\left[{55 \over 4} + 12\ln\left(3 \over 8\right)\right]\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: It seems you are assuming the problem the OP is having is in setting up the integral. What makes you think this is the case? In any case, I don't think your answer is helpful.